# Prompt function against HTML doc loading in JS

Tags: javascript, html, loading, prompt

```
let ans=document.querySelector("p")
let text;
text=Math.floor(Math.random()*100+1);

flag=true;
while(flag===true){
    let guessed=parseInt(prompt("Guess the number?"));
    if (guessed===text){
        ans.textContent="Congratulations! U guessed it right!";
        flag=false;
    }
    else if (guessed>text){
        ans.textContent="Guess lower!";
    }
    else if (guessed<text){
        ans.textContent="Guess higher!";
    }
    
}
```

How do i prompt the user using prompt() function after the HTML has completely loaded?

The above code will not load complete html and prompts the user immediately as you reload the page.

Comment: I would change the name of `text` to `number` since it is really confusing.